# DeflateReset or clear API for allocated InflateRaw (fast-zlib) object

Tags: node.js, zlib, inflate

we are using npm fast-zlib lib for deflating a compressed load.
The code is pretty simple

```
let zipped = getItFromSomeWhere();
let inflateRaw = new fastZlib.InflateRaw({
            chunkSize: 4 * 1024
        });

inflateRaw.process(zipped).toString()
```

The **inflateRaw** object allocation is done before each load processing call.
I'm wondering if there is a way to reuse the **inflateRaw** instead of creating each time. It definitely would improve the performance